# CTRL+. no longer working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I had installed Visual Studio 2015 Community and Resharper 9 on a clean windows 10 machine. Somehow I had the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> working for me, it would bring up quick actions and refactoring window. I'm not sure if the shortcut was mapped to Resharper or VS.

Somehow, I have lost this shortcut, the context menu says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> should do the same, but the shortcut does nothing at all. How can I get my shortcut back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshaper provides two Default Keyboard Shortcut Schemes.As

1. Visual Studio This scheme aims to minimize conflicts with Visual
   Studio's own keyboard shortcuts.
2. ReSharper 2.x/IntelliJ IDEA This scheme shares the majority of
   shortcuts with those used in IntelliJ IDEA and its derivative web
   development IDEs. It provides a common keyboard-centric experience
   among all JetBrains development environments.

[Resharper keyboard shortcut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html?origin=old_help)

What you are looking for is go to Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard.
find choose Visual studio scheme and save.Restart IDE.

Comment: Thanks @amey, reseting to visual studio scheme ultimately resolved my missing shortcuts issue, although the what I was looking for in CTRL+. is now mapped to ALT+Enter. I still don't know where the CTRL+. shortcut came from and why it disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/07/23/critical-issue-with-resharper-9-1-2-in-visual-studio-2015-rtm-workarounds-and-estimates/

1. Go to ReSharper’s editor appearance options (ReSharper > Options > Environment > Editor > Editor Appearance) and disable Enable action bar for action indicators and show it next to the left margin.
2. Go to in ReSharper’s code analysis options (ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Settings) and disable Do not show Visual Studio bulb (VS action will be merged into ReSharper bulb).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly what popup you meant.

- By selecting a `method/property/class/...` and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> the **refactor this** popup opens.
- If you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>RETURN</kbd> the **quick Action** popup opens.

Both shortcuts are the default from ReSharper.